# Combining hover functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many `<spans>`s which need to group to change opacity after hover.  All of them need to have unique IDs.  Is there a way to combine all these hover functions to one function?

**jQuery**

```
//09    
    $('#c_09_241a, #c_09_241b, #c_09_241c, #c_09_241d').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_09_241a, #c_09_241b, #c_09_241c, #c_09_241d').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_09_241a, #c_09_241b, #c_09_241c, #c_09_241d').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    }); 
    $('#c_09_242a, #c_09_242b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_09_242a, #c_09_242b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_09_242a, #c_09_242b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_09_245a, #c_09_245b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_09_245a, #c_09_245b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_09_245a, #c_09_245b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_09_246a, #c_09_246b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_09_246a, #c_09_246b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_09_246a, #c_09_246b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });

    //08    
    $('#c_08_235a, #c_08_235b, #c_08_235c, #c_08_235d').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_08_235a, #c_08_235b, #c_08_235c, #c_08_235d').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_08_235a, #c_08_235b, #c_08_235c, #c_08_235d').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    }); 
    $('#c_08_236a, #c_08_236b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_08_236a, #c_08_236b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_08_236a, #c_08_236b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_08_239a, #c_08_239b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_08_239a, #c_08_239b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_08_239a, #c_08_239b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_08_240a, #c_08_240b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_08_240a, #c_08_240b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_08_240a, #c_08_240b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });

    //07    
    $('#c_07_227a, #c_07_227b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_07_227a, #c_07_227b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_07_227a, #c_07_227b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_07_228a, #c_07_228b, #c_07_228c').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_07_228a, #c_07_228b, #c_07_228c').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_07_228a, #c_07_228b, #c_07_228c').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_07_007a, #c_07_007b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_07_007a, #c_07_007b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_07_007a, #c_07_007b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_07_008a, #c_07_008b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_07_008a, #c_07_008b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_07_008a, #c_07_008b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="rzuty09p" class="rzuty">
            <span id="c_09_241a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_241b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_241c" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_241d" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_242a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_242b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_243" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_244" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_245a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_245b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_246a" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_246b" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
        </div>  

<div id="rzuty08p" class="rzuty">
            <span id="c_08_235a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_235b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_235c" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_235d" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_236a" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_236b" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_237" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_238" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_239a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_239b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_240a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_240b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
        </div>      

<div id="rzuty07p" class="rzuty">
            <span id="c_07_226" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_227a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_227b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_228a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_228b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_228c" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_229" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_005" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_006" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_007a" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_007b" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_008a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_008b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var groups = [
    '09_241', '09_242', '09_245', '09_246',
    '08_235', '08_236', '08_239', '08_240',
    '07_227', '07_228', '07_007', '07_008'
];

$.each(groups, function(i, group) {

    var $group = $('[id^=c_' + group + ']');

    $group.hover(function() {
        $group.stop(true, true).css('opacity', '1');
    }, function() {
        $group.stop(true, true).css('opacity', '0');
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W8GA3/

This is similar to @Matt's solution, with the following key differences:

1. **Sane Selectors** - There's no need to add all those selectors by hand. Simply use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all elements that start with a given string.
2. **Selector caching** - If there's one thing you can do to your code to keep it fast, it's [selector caching](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/).
3. **$.each** - We're using [jQuery's `each` helper](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop through the array, since it also supports older browsers (`forEach` is not supported in IE < 9).

---

If you want to, you could even build that original `groups` array dynamically, which will make this *much* easier to maintain:

```
var groups = [];

$('[id^=c_]').each(function() {
    // Extract group number from ID
    var group = this.id.substring(2, 8);
    // If the ID is not in the groups array, add it
    ~$.inArray( group, groups ) || groups.push( group );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W8GA3/1/

Comment: this is super cool, new level for me, thx a lot

Comment: @gidzior - Glad it helped you. You might have to modify some bits of the code depending on your naming conventions. `$('[id^=c_]')` and `this.id.substring(2, 8)` make a lot of assumptions, and I hope I wasn't too wrong...